# Deepspeech training

Tags: python, mozilla-deepspeech

i tried to run training for small data, using Mozilla DeepSpeech.
All requirements are installed.

`./bin/run-ldc93s1.sh`

But i faced this problem:

```
    `Loading the LM will be faster if you build a binary file.
Reading data/lm/lm.binary
----5---10---15---20---25---30---35---40---45---50---55---60---65---70---75---80---85---90---95--100
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'lm::FormatLoadException'
  what():  ../kenlm/lm/read_arpa.cc:65 in void lm::ReadARPACounts(util::FilePiece&, std::vector<long unsigned int>&) threw FormatLoadException.
first non-empty line was "version https://git-lfs.github.com/spec/v1" not \data\. Byte: 43
Fatal Python error: Aborted

Thread 0x00007f98e2033700 (most recent call first):
  File "/home/AU/li_d/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 296 in wait
  File "/home/AU/li_d/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/queue.py", line 170 in get
  File "/home/AU/li_d/Desktop/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/summary/writer/event_file_writer.py", line 159 in run
  File "/home/AU/li_d/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 926 in _bootstrap_inner
  File "/home/AU/li_d/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 890 in _bootstrap

Thread 0x00007f98e2834700 (most recent call first):
  File "/home/AU/li_d/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 296 in wait
  File "/home/AU/li_d/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/queue.py", line 170 in get
  File "/home/AU/li_d/Desktop/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/summary/writer/event_file_writer.py", line 159 in run
  File "/home/AU/li_d/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 926 in _bootstrap_inner
  File "/home/AU/li_d/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 890 in _bootstrap

Current thread 0x00007f99ed0ab740 (most recent call first):
  File "/home/AU/li_d/Desktop/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ds_ctcdecoder/swigwrapper.py", line 279 in init
  File "/home/AU/li_d/Desktop/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ds_ctcdecoder/__init__.py", line 30 in __init__
  File "/home/AU/li_d/Desktop/DeepSpeech2/evaluate.py", line 48 in evaluate
  File "DeepSpeech.py", line 675 in test
  File "DeepSpeech.py", line 942 in main
  File "/home/AU/li_d/Desktop/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/absl/app.py", line 250 in _run_main
  File "/home/AU/li_d/Desktop/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/absl/app.py", line 299 in run
  File "DeepSpeech.py", line 965 in <module>
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Does anybody have any suggestions?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You forgot to install git lfs

Comment: run this `curl -s https://packagecloud.io/install/repositories/github/git-lfs/script.deb.sh | sudo bash` and if error occurs use python3.6

Comment: Thank for your respond, but it's installed

Comment: using the INSTALL.sh script ?

Comment: install git lfs using above command and provide output of `pip3 freeze | grep deep`

Comment: No, using conda install -c conda-forge/label/cf201901 git-lfs

Comment: I cannot do it, because i am not root user

Comment: can you run the command `git lfs` in terminal and see what does it print ?

Comment: yes it shows available commands

Comment: Are the errors below the git lfs, also related to git-lfs?

Comment: No thats either your data conflict or you messed up the versions, provide the `pip freeze | grep deep`

Comment: ' deepspeech-gpu==0.6.0'

Comment: have you checked deepspeech issues? there are over 20 issues with same traceback that points to git lfs installation problem, I had the same issue a while back and I installed git lfs using the above command in venv of python3.6.8 and everything worked like charm.

Comment: `https://github.com/mozilla/DeepSpeech/issues/2052`     I used deepspeech 0.6.0 too, So first install git lfs correctly and can you run git lfs without activating the venv as the code uses the global environment for git lfs.

Comment: Okay, got it. Thank you so much. I will check it.

Comment: Yeah, out of virtualenv git lfs works)

Comment: and out of virtual what does `pip3 freeze | grep deep` yield ?

Comment: absolutely nothing

Answer (score 0):

Please validate the following once in your system:

1.Check git-lfs installed properly

2.Do proper checkout from github repository code and use appropriate models for the particular deepspeech version.